# JQuery Ajax XMLHttprequest successful but not returning success message

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to create a contact form that collects a name, email, message type and message from a form. So far the validation of the fields, getting the information and sending the email all work correctly. The main problem I can't seem to fix is that once the information is submitted There is suppose to be a success message that is shown once the email is sent. This is where my problem is.

Here is the function that is suppose to do all the work.:

**JQuery**

```
// make our ajax request to the server
function submitForm(formData) {

    $.ajax({    
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Scripts/send_email.php',
        dataType: 'json',       
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        /*timeout: 8000, // timeout after 8 seconds*/
        success: function(data,textStatus,XMLHttpRequest) {
            $('form #error-div').removeClass('').addClass((data.error === true) ? 'xmark-img' : 'check-img');

                if ($('form #error-div').hasClass('check-img')) {
                    $('form #error-div').addClass('success').html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast'); 
                }

                $('form').slideUp().hide();
                $('form').find('span').hide();
                $('form').find('label').hide();
                $('form').find('input').hide();
                $('form').find('select').hide();
                $('form').find('textarea').hide();

                setTimeout($('form #error-div').fadeOut('slow'), 4000); 
                return true;        
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('form #error-div').removeClass('').addClass('xmark-img').addClass('error-box').html('');
                $('form #error-div').html('There was an ' + errorThrown +
                                          ' error due to a ' + textStatus + 
                                          ' condition.'+ 'XMLHttpRequest: ' + XMLHttpRequest[0] + 
                                          ' Error Thrown: ' + errorThrown + '<br/>' + 
                                          ' textStatus:  ' + textStatus + ' <br />msg: ' 
                                          + msg + '<br />data: ' + data).fadeIn('fast')

            return false;
        },              
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {
                $('form')[0].reset();           
        }
    }); 
};
```

Right now after the form is submitted the error-div shows the sending message animated gif and I do receive the email. But, it does not execute the success or error callback. Using firebug I also get an error "TypeError: data is null". I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong since the email does get sent.

---

**PHP Script**

```
<?php 
sleep(3);

//Sanitize incoming data and store in variable
$name = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])));
$email = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'])));
$message = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'])));
$message_type = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message_type'])));   

$humancheck = $_POST['humancheck'];
$honeypot = $_POST['honeypot'];

if ($honeypot == 'http://' && empty($humancheck)) {         
        //Validate data and return success or error message
        $error_message = '';    
        $reg_exp = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[\.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/";

        if (!preg_match($reg_exp, $email)) {
                $error_message .= "You must provide a valid e-mail address <br/>";             
        }

        if (empty($name)) {
                $error_message .= "You must include your name <br/>";
        }
        if (empty($message_type)) {
                $error_message .= "You must select a message type for your message. <br/>";
        }               
        if (empty($message)) {
                $error_message .= "You must enter a message. <br/>";
        }       
        if (!empty($error_message)) {
                $return['msg'] = 'Error: The request was successful but your form is not filled out correctly. '.$error_message;
                $return['error'] = true;
                exit();
        }else {
                    $ToEmail = "tony.hall@tonyhallportfolio.com";
                    $EmailSubject_Response = $message_type." from ".$name." (".$email.")"; 

                    $mailheader_Response = "From: ".$email."\r\n";
                    $mailheader_Response .= "To: ".$ToEmail."\r\n"; 
                    $mailheader_Response .= "Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n";
                    $mailheader_Response .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 

                    $MESSAGE_BODY_Response  = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://tonyhallportfolio.com/CSS/email_style.css' /></head><body>";
                    $MESSAGE_BODY_Response .= "<div class='header'><img src='http://tonyhallportfolio.com/images/logo-ns.png'/></div>\n";
                    $MESSAGE_BODY_Response .= "<hr/>\n";
                    $MESSAGE_BODY_Response .= "<div class='content'><h3>E-Mail Message via Tonyhallportfolio.com </h3>";
                    $MESSAGE_BODY_Response .= "<h4>Name: </h4>".$name."\n"; 
                    $MESSAGE_BODY_Response .= "<h4>Email: </h4>".$email."\n"; 
                    $MESSAGE_BODY_Response .= "<h4>Message Details: </h4>".nl2br($message)."</div>"; 
                    $MESSAGE_BODY_Response .= "<body/><html/>";

                    mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject_Response, $MESSAGE_BODY_Response, $mailheader_Response) or die ("Failure");

                    if($message_type == "Website Inquiry"){
                        $EmailSubject_Inq = "Conformation of ".$message_type." sent via tonyhallportfolio.com"; 

                        $mailheader_Inq = "From: ".$ToEmail."\r\n";
                        $mailheader_Inq .= "To: ".$email."\r\n"; 
                        $mailheader_Inq .= "Reply-To: ".$ToEmail."\r\n";
                        $mailheader_Inq .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 

                        $MESSAGE_BODY_Inq  = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://tonyhallportfolio.com/CSS/email_style.css' /></head><body>";
                        $MESSAGE_BODY_Inq .= "<div class='header'><img src='http://tonyhallportfolio.com/images/logo-ns.png'/></div>\n";
                        $MESSAGE_BODY_Inq .= "<hr/>\n";
                        $MESSAGE_BODY_Inq .= "<div class='content'>"."<p>Thank you for reaching out to me in order to build a website for yourself or your business. This email confirms that your message has been sent. Please allow me ample time to respond back to you as I may have others inquiring for my services. I will make sure to review the information you sent me and respond in a reasonable amount of time. Thanks again for your inquiry.</p>";

                        $MESSAGE_BODY_Inq .= "<h3>".$message_type." for Tony Hall via Tonyhallportfolio.com </h3>";
                        $MESSAGE_BODY_Inq .= "<h4>Name: </h4>".$name."\n"; 
                        $MESSAGE_BODY_Inq .= "<h4>Email: </h4>".$email."\n"; 
                        $MESSAGE_BODY_Inq .= "<h4>Message Details: </h4>".nl2br($message)."</div>"; 
                        $MESSAGE_BODY_Inq .= "<body/><html/>";

                        mail($email, $EmailSubject_Inq, $MESSAGE_BODY_Inq, $mailheader_Inq) or die ("Failure");

                        $return['msg'] = '<h3>'.$name.' ,Thank you for your message. </h3>';    
                        $return['error'] = false;

                    }else{
                        $EmailSubject_msg = "Conformation of ".$message_type." sent via tonyhallportfolio.com"; 

                        $mailheader_msg   = "From: ".$ToEmail."\r\n";
                        $mailheader_msg  .= "To: ".$email."\r\n"; 
                        $mailheader_msg  .= "Reply-To:".$email."\r\n";
                        $mailheader_msg  .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 

                        $MESSAGE_BODY_msg  = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://tonyhallportfolio.com/CSS/email_style.css' /></head><body>";
                        $MESSAGE_BODY_msg .= "<div class='header'><img src='http://tonyhallportfolio.com/images/logo-ns.png'/></div>\n";
                        $MESSAGE_BODY_msg .= "<hr/>\n";
                        $MESSAGE_BODY_msg .= "<div class='content'>"."<p>Thank you for leaving me a message on my E-Portfolio website. This email confirms that your message has been sent. I will make sure to review your message and take your comments and/or suggestions in consideration to help improve the site. Your input is greatly appreciated.</p>";

                        $MESSAGE_BODY_msg .= "<h3>".$message_type." for Tony Hall via Tonyhallportfolio.com </h3>";
                        $MESSAGE_BODY_msg .= "<h4>Name: </h4>".$name."\n"; 
                        $MESSAGE_BODY_msg .= "<h4>Email: </h4>".$email."\n"; 
                        $MESSAGE_BODY_msg .= "<h4>Message Details: </h4>".nl2br($message)."</div>"; 
                        $MESSAGE_BODY_msg .= "<body/><html/>";

                        mail($email, $EmailSubject_msg, $MESSAGE_BODY_msg, $mailheader_msg) or die ("Failure");

                        $return['msg'] = $name.' ,Thank you for your message.'; 
                        $return['error'] = false;
                        exit(); 
                    }
             }          


}else {
    $return['msg'] = 'There was a problem with your submission. Please try again.';
    $return['error'] = true;
    exit(); 
}

?>
```

Comment: This is most common issue when dealing with a malformed JSON response. What is the output of the error callback, with all that logs?

Comment: your success response that you get from server must also be in JSON format. Can you post your success response here?

Comment: it gives me referenceError:xmlHttpRequest is not defined. ReferenceError: xmlHttpRequest is not defined
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js
Line 2

Comment: Once the error callback is executed a message displaying the error thrown and text status is suppose to appear in the error-div.

Comment: could anyone give me a hint to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: after playing around with the code some more I got it to the point now where it is executing the error callback. But, again sending the email is successful. It is returning a timeout error. @Kishore

Comment: this is my first time working with json. What do you mean by malformed json response? @rcdmk

Comment: A malformed JSON response is an invalid JSON response. This means the response is not valid JSON or it contains some errors in the format. Please see http://json.org for more info about JSON.

Comment: can you post your server-side script too?

Comment: so you have a $return array there, are you doing some kind of json_encode($return) before echoing that?

Comment: Wow..that probably is the problem right there. I do remember having that at one point. It must have gotten buried in code and deleted at some point. I'm getting atleast some respons from the form and I should be headed in the right direction. I'll keep working at it and keep updated. @Onheiron

Comment: Yes this was my problem, everything is working fine now. Thank you for your help I really appreciate it @Onheiron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning a `$return` array there, you'll need to converti it into JSON format before echoing it like this:

```
echo json_encode($return);
```